# Most efficient algorithm to rewrite tree

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, tree

Say we have a tree stored like this:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 5
1 5 6 
1 5 6 7
1 5 6 7 8
1 9 
1 9 10
1 9 10 11
1 9 10 11 12
1 9 10 13
```

If we were to draw this tree, it would look something like:

[image]

What I need to do is rewrite the tree into a name-parent-children type format. In this example, this would look like:

```
[{

        "name": "1",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "2",
                "parent": "1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "3",
                        "parent": "2",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "4",
                                "parent": "3",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "5",
                "parent": "1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "6",
                        "parent": "5",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "7",
                                "parent": "6",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "8",
                                        "parent": "7",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "9",
                "parent": "1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "10",
                        "parent": "9",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "11",
                                "parent": "10",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "12",
                                        "parent": "11",
                                        "children": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "13",
                                "parent": "10",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    
                ]
            }
        ]


    }];
```

This is a JavaScript array. I want to know what the most efficient algorithm to achieve this conversion would be. If you're wondering why I put Python as a tag, this is because the algorithm will be written entirely in Python, but the list will ultimately be used in a JavaScript program that will display the tree.

Comment: So what your input data looks like?

Comment: If you want the most efficient algorithm, you should make this a nested dict.  Storing the children as an array is going to force you to do iterative lookups to locate each node.

Comment: @NenadVracar my data comes from a database. I forgot to mention this in the question, but I have a SAN chess position as a record in the database. So, just think of my data as the data I showed in the question but with chess moves instead of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by doing a nested iteration that turns your list of strings into a nested dict:

```
data = """
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 5
1 5 6 
1 5 6 7
1 5 6 7 8
1 9 
1 9 10
1 9 10 11
1 9 10 11 12
1 9 10 13
"""

tree = {}
for line in data.split("\n"):
    node = tree
    for n in line.split():
        node = node.setdefault(n, {})
print(tree)
```

prints:

```
{'1': {'2': {'3': {'4': {}}}, '5': {'6': {'7': {'8': {}}}}, '9': {'10': {'11': {'12': {}}, '13': {}}}}}
```

Then we can massage the nested dict into your JS structure with a simple recursive function:

```
def node_to_js(tree, parent=None):
    return [{
            "name": name,
            "parent": parent,
            "children": node_to_js(node, name)
        }
        for name, node in tree.items()
    ]

print(node_to_js(tree))
```

prints:

```
[{'name': '1', 'parent': None, 'children': [{'name': '2', 'parent': '1', 'children': [{'name': '3', 'parent': '2', 'children': [{'name': '4', 'parent': '3', 'children': []}]}]}, {'name': '5', 'parent': '1', 'children': [{'name': '6', 'parent': '5', 'children': [{'name': '7', 'parent': '6', 'children': [{'name': '8', 'parent': '7', 'children': []}]}]}]}, {'name': '9', 'parent': '1', 'children': [{'name': '10', 'parent': '9', 'children': [{'name': '11', 'parent': '10', 'children': [{'name': '12', 'parent': '11', 'children': []}]}, {'name': '13', 'parent': '10', 'children': []}]}]}]}]
```

which you can easily JSONify in order to get it into your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your mind, and want to do this in JS, here's a function that seems to do it:

```js
const makeTree = (input, parent = null,
  edges = input.split ('\n') .filter (Boolean) .map (s => s .trim () .split (' ')) .map (ns => ns .slice (-2)) .slice (1),
  vertices = [...new Set (edges .flat ())]
) => vertices 
  .filter (v => edges .some (([a, b]) => parent == null || a == parent && b == v))
  .map (name => ({name, parent, children: makeTree (input, name, edges, vertices)}))


const input = `
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 5
1 5 6 
1 5 6 7
1 5 6 7 8
1 9 
1 9 10
1 9 10 11
1 9 10 11 12
1 9 10 13
`

console .log (makeTree (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We parse the input into a collection of edges (using the last two numbers in the list, and removing the first element, which has only one vertex).  Then we extract the vertices as the unique nodes in the edges, and, starting with a `null` parent, we find all the nodes that use our parent on the `to` side of an edge, then recur with its id, converting to your object format as we go.

Comment: Thank you. I will stick to the first solution for now, but I will eventually come back to this and compare efficiencies.